# View free space on offline mapped network drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, quota, mappeddrive, windows

We provide all of our users with a mapped network drive (H:) which we have re-directed my documents to. Using FSRM on the file server, each user is restricted to 5GB of disk space.

Windows automatically sets this up as an offline folder, and the sync works well, especially for laptop users who are often away from the network.

When users are connected to the LAN, Windows Explorer shows how much of their 5GB quota they are using. However... when they disconnect from the LAN, it shows how much space is free on their local drive.

Consequently, users who work a lot of the time on slow network links and are mostly in offline mode can exceed their quota whilst offline. When they return to the office and connect to the LAN, they find they can't save data any longer.

Is there someway to configure windows to keep track of the quota, and display the free space to users whilst working in offline mode?

(This issue appears to be even worse with Windows 8, which prefers to work in offline mode all of the time by default, even on fast networks)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is a powershell script that fires on login that checks their local cache and pops a message warning the user if they have exceeded the quota.

Answer (score -3):

Somewhat convoluted, but you might be able to create a 5GB partition on the local machine(s), then locally map it as the user's "my documents" directory.  That way the user could never write more than 5GB.  I don't know of another way to locally set a size limit at the folder level.

Sort of alluded to here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532775/is-it-possible-to-limit-folder-size-in-a-windows-environment

Comment: He might be able to do that, yeah. Along the same lines, he might be able to figure out a way to cut off his arm with the file server as well.  I'll leave it at that and let you ponder the implications of my statement.